# Laravel using accessor to return a country name from country code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that has `country_code` and `country_name`.

Each user in my database has country_code on their account. What I want to do is automatically return the country_name instead of the country_code for that user.

I have setup an accessor in my User model, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public function getCountryCodeAttribute($value): string
{
    return Country::firstWhere('country_code', $value)->get('country_name');
}
```

It keeps still returning the `country_code`

Any help would be great

Comment: How do you use the country code attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with an QueryBuilder() that returns your model. To access a property on the model, simply access it as it was an property.

```
return Country::firstWhere('country_code', $value)->country_name;
```

For exposing it for your endpoint, use the User model append property, where you can add custom Eloquent Setters to the serialization.

```
class User {
    protected $appends = [
        'country_code',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hey, It still doesnt seem to be working. Should this method be in the Countries or Users model?

Comment: it should be in the User model

Comment: And when you say "Hey, It still doesnt seem to be working." please describe what is happening, returning null, exception?

Comment: Sorry. What i meant was, that its returning the full user data with the country code still

Comment: In the database, the users 'country' is set to the country code, when i return all the users, i want to automatically change that country_code into the correct country_name

Comment: How do you access the country_code, somewhere you have to access it? how do you transform your model etc.

Comment: In the customers controller, just using User::all()

Comment: Super we got to the core, i have updated the question :)